# Log plot and linear plot plotted in one view

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I have the following code:

```
q := 1.6*10^-19;
me := 9.1*10^-31; (* Free electron rest mass in kg *)
h :=  6.63*10^-34;  (* Reduced Planck's constant in J.s *)
kb := 1.38*10^-23;(* Boltzmann constant in J/K *)
Jschottky[V_, T_] := (2 q*(2 \[Pi] me)^0.5 kb^1.5)/h^2*(0.3)^0.5*
  Exp[-0.18/((kb*T)/q)] (Exp[(q*V)/(kb*T)] - 1);
LogPlot[Abs[Jschottky[V, 77]], {V, -0.5, 0.5}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Voltage (V)", 
   "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(J\), SuperscriptBox[\(T\), \(3/2\)]]\)"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 15}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red} , 
 AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> 400, FrameStyle -> Black, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{#, Superscript[10, Log10@#]} & /@ ({10^-21, 10^-11, 
       10^-1, 10^9, 10^19}), None}, {Automatic, None}}]

Plot[Abs[Jschottky[V, 77]], {V, -0.5, 0.5}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Voltage (V)", 
   "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(J\), SuperscriptBox[\(T\), \(3/2\)]]\)"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 15}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue} , 
 AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> 400, FrameStyle -> Black]
```

I get the following results:

[image]
[image]

Now I want to plot them on the same plot with the logplot on the left y axis and the linear plot on the right yaxis. What should I do? Also any recommendations for a good grayscale plot of the same?

Comment: Please supply the definition for your `Jschottky` function. Without it, it is impossible to work with code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how I missed that. I have added it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably do not want to use SetDelayed (:=) for your constant values here. You can simply use Set (=). This will avoid unnecessary evaluation time.

Answer (score 5):

```
q := 1.6*10^-19;
me := 9.1*10^-31;(*Free electron rest mass in kg*)h := 
 6.63*10^-34;(*Reduced Planck's constant in J.s*)kb := 
 1.38*10^-23;(*Boltzmann constant in J/K*)
Jschottky[V_, T_] := (2 q*(2 \[Pi] me)^0.5 kb^1.5)/h^2*(0.3)^0.5*
  Exp[-0.18/((kb*T)/q)] (Exp[(q*V)/(kb*T)] - 1);
p1 = LogPlot[Abs[Jschottky[V, 77]], {V, -0.5, 0.5}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Voltage (V)", 
    "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(J\), SuperscriptBox[\(T\), \(3/2\)]]\)"}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 15}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
  AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> 400, FrameStyle -> Black, 
  ImagePadding -> {{100, 100}, {80, 80}}, FrameTicksStyle -> Red, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{#, Superscript[10, Log10@#]} & /@ ({10^-21, 10^-11,
         10^-1, 10^9, 10^19}), None}, {Automatic, None}}]

p2 = Plot[Abs[Jschottky[V, 77]], {V, -0.5, 0.5}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{None, 
     "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(J\), SuperscriptBox[\(T\), \(3/2\)]]\)"}, \
{None, None}}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 15}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}, AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio, 
  ImageSize -> 400, ImagePadding -> {{100, 100}, {80, 80}}, 
  FrameStyle -> Black, FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Blue]
Overlay[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How should I make the x-axis to be black in color?

Comment: For p1, use ```FrameTicksStyle -> {{Red, None}, {None, Black}}```. This sets the color for {{left,right},{top,bottom}}.

Answer (score 1):

On a side note (but too big to fit in a comment), you can speed up the `Jschottky` function evaluation by about 13x by using `FunctionCompile`:

```
f = Function[{Typed[V, "Real64"], Typed[T, "Integer64"]},
  Module[{q, me, h, kb},
   q = 1.6*10^-19;
   me = 9.1*10^-31;
   h = 6.63*10^-34;
   kb = 1.38*10^-23;
   (2 q*(2 \[Pi] me)^0.5 kb^1.5)/h^2*(0.3)^0.5*
    Exp[-0.18/((kb*T)/q)] (Exp[(q*V)/(kb*T)] - 1)
   ]
  ]
```

and then:

```
cf = FunctionCompile[f]
```

On my machine I get the following timings:

```
In[.]:= Do[Jschottky[RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}], 77], 100000] // AbsoluteTiming
Out[.]= {0.777224, Null}

In[.]:= Do[cf[RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}], 77], 100000] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[.]= {0.0563924, Null}
```

Comment: Thank you, what all functions does it work for? And what are you actually doing by executing it this way?

Comment: Almost everything I know is contained in this presentation by Tom Wickham-Jones. It's worth watching! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LulZszTJH4g